# Reduce sum with condition in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am given a 2D Tensor with stochastic rows. After applying `tf.math.greater()` and `tf.cast(tf.int32)` I am left with a Tensor with 0's and 1's. I now want to apply reduce sum onto that matrix but with a condition: If there was at least one 1 summed and a 0 follows I want to remove all following 1 aswell, meaning `1 0 1` should result in `1` instead of `2`.

I have tried to solve the Problem with `tf.scan()`, but I was not able to come up with a function yet that is able to handle starting 0's, because the row might look like: `0 0 0 1 0 1` 
One idea was to set the lower part of the matrix to one (bc I know everything left from the diagonal will always be 0) and then have a function like `tf.scan()` run to filter out the spots (see code and error message below).

`Let z be the matrix after tf.cast.`

```
helper = tf.matrix_band_part(tf.ones_like(z), -1, 0)
z = tf.math.logical_or(tf.cast(z, tf.bool), tf.cast(helper,tf.bool))
z = tf.cast(z, tf.int32)
z = tf.scan(lambda a, x: x if a == 1 else 0 ,z)
```

Resulting in:

`ValueError: Incompatible shape for value ([]), expected ([5])`

Comment: So, just to see if I am understanding correctly, for each row, you want to count the number of ones in the first "group" of consecutive ones, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, this is one way to do what you want without scanning or looping. It may be a bit convoluted, and is actually iterating the columns twice (one cumsum and one cumprod), but being vectorized operations I think it is probably faster. Code is TF 2.x but runs the same in TF 1.x (except for the last line obviously).

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Example data
a = tf.constant([[0, 0, 0, 0],
                 [1, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 1, 1, 0],
                 [0, 1, 0, 1],
                 [1, 1, 1, 0],
                 [1, 1, 0, 1],
                 [0, 1, 1, 1],
                 [1, 1, 1, 1]])
# Cumsum columns
c = tf.math.cumsum(a, axis=1)
# Column-wise differences
diffs = tf.concat([tf.ones([tf.shape(c)[0], 1], c.dtype), c[:, 1:] - c[:, :-1]], axis=1)
# Find point where we should not sum anymore (cumsum is not zero and difference is zero)
cutoff = tf.equal(a, 0) & tf.not_equal(c, 0)
# Make mask
mask = tf.math.cumprod(tf.dtypes.cast(~cutoff, tf.uint8), axis=1)
# Compute result
result = tf.reduce_max(c * tf.dtypes.cast(mask, c.dtype), axis=1)
print(result.numpy())
# [0 1 2 1 3 2 3 4]
```

Comment: It's probably faster to not use `cumsum` (and later `reduce_max`), but instead just the `mask` via `cumprod`, and then directly `reduce_sum` in the end.

Comment: @Albert Thanks for the feedback. But I use the `cumsum` to define the mask, to find the first `0` after a `1` (I have simplified how I make the mask though because I realised it was more complicated than it should).

Comment: @jdehesa Ah, I skimmed that part too fast. I thought that you simply do `mask = cumprod(tf.cast(tf.not_equal(a, 0), tf.uint8))`. Wouldn't that be easier?

Comment: @Albert The thing is OP wants to compute the sum up until the first `0` after a `1`, so that fails for rows starting with `0`.