# Find the maximum number of consecutive ones in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have found solutions in

Matlab: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/85143-find-maximum-number-of-consecutive-negative-values

Numpy: [Find consecutive ones in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35610834/find-consecutive-ones-in-numpy-array)

But not in Tensorflow. The closest question I've found is this:
[Reduce sum with condition in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58708874/reduce-sum-with-condition-in-tensorflow)

However this only counts the first group of ones, rather than finding the largest group. Basically, the problem would be easily solved if there was a Tensorflow equivalent of Matlab's RCUMSUMC

https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28685-rcumsumc

My input is a binary tensor of shape NxHxW, and the output is expected to be NxW, where each column represents the maximum number of consecutive ones:

```
Input = [[1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1],
         [1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0],
         [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0]]

Output = [4,6,3]
```

Comment: Can you provide a simple example of the input you have and the expected output?

Comment: Edited with sample input and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Here is how you could do the same for a 3-dimensional tensor searching for groups of ones across the second dimension:

```
import tensorflow as tf

inp = tf.random.stateless_uniform((3, 4, 5), [0, 0], 0, 2, tf.int32)
tf.print(inp)
# [[[0 1 0 0 0]
#   [0 0 0 1 1]
#   [0 1 1 0 0]
#   [0 0 0 0 0]]
# 
#  [[1 1 0 0 0]
#   [0 1 1 0 0]
#   [0 1 0 1 0]
#   [0 0 0 0 0]]
# 
#  [[1 1 1 0 0]
#   [0 0 1 1 1]
#   [0 1 1 0 1]
#   [0 1 0 0 0]]]
# Pad with ones to avoid all-zeros
inp = tf.pad(inp, [(0, 1), (0, 0), (0, 0)], constant_values=1)
s = tf.shape(inp)
# Transpose and reshape
inp_t = tf.reshape(tf.transpose(inp, [0, 2, 1]), [-1, s[1]])
# Surround with zeros
inp_t = tf.pad(inp_t, [(0, 0), (1, 1)])
# Find bounds of groups of ones
groups = tf.reshape(tf.where(tf.not_equal(inp_t[:, 1:], inp_t[:, :-1])), [-1, 2, 2])
# Compute group sizes
group_sizes = groups[:, 1, 1] - groups[:, 0, 1]
# Find maximum group sizes
max_ones_group = tf.math.segment_max(group_sizes, groups[:, 0, 0], name=None)
# Reshape back
out = tf.reshape(max_ones_group, [s[0], s[2]])[:-1]
tf.print(out)
# [[0 1 1 1 1]
#  [1 3 1 1 0]
#  [1 2 3 1 2]]
```

---

Assuming that the input is a binary tensor (only zeros and ones), this is one way to do that:

```
import tensorflow as tf

inp = tf.constant([[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                   [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]])
# Surround with zeros
inp = tf.pad(inp, [(0, 0), (1, 1)])
# Find bounds of groups of ones
groups = tf.reshape(tf.where(tf.not_equal(inp[:, 1:], inp[:, :-1])), [-1, 2, 2])
# Compute group sizes
group_sizes = groups[:, 1, 1] - groups[:, 0, 1]
# Find maximum group sizes
max_ones_group = tf.math.segment_max(group_sizes, groups[:, 0, 0], name=None)
tf.print(max_ones_group)
# [4 6 3]
```

Comment: It works for N=1, but what if we have many samples? For input of shape NxHxW, the output needs to be NxW.

Comment: @metalruka I added another example with a 3D tensor.

Comment: Just a side note, this fails if there are no ones in the input array. Padding the input with a single row of ones is an easy workaround.

Comment: @metalruka You're right, thanks for the feedback. Yes, I think padding is the easiest solution, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, this is a bit convoluted. But it was fun coming up with this. (Tested both on TF 2.0 and TF 1.15)

```
# Let's assume a simpler example for demonstration [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
tf_a = tf.constant([[1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1],
         [1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0],
         [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0]])

# You get the cumsum [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
tf_a_sum = tf.cumsum(tf_a, axis=1)
# You get the range  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
tf_range = tf.range(tf_a.shape[1])

# You get the difference [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
tf_diff = tf_range - tf_a_sum
# To make sure it's starting with 0
tf_diff = tf_diff - tf.reduce_min(tf_diff, axis=1, keepdims=True)

# Now comes the tricky bit. We are using segment_sum
# I would have liked to achieve this with tf.map_fn but segment_sum didn't play nicely with map_fn
# So we are first unstacking the arrays on rows
# Applying segment_sum to individual rows
# And restacking them

tf_list_diff = tf.unstack(tf_diff)
tf_list_a = tf.unstack(tf_a)

# [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1] => summing segment-wise with [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
# Gives [3,1]
# And you get max of that which is 3
tf_res = tf.stack([tf.reduce_max(tf.math.segment_sum(a, diff)) for a, diff in zip(tf_list_a, tf_list_diff)])
```

**Warning**: This will work as long as you're interested in getting the number of 1s in an array containing 0s and 1s **only**. This won't work if you have other numbers in the array. So this way of solving is very specific to the problem you want to solve.